# SVG 'S' Bezier curve to mathematical formulae

Tags: javascript, svg, canvas, bezier

I have the following SVG path: `M 0, 100  S 27, 2, 200 0`.

I'm trying to use the Bezier equations from [here](https://javascript.info/bezier-curve) to convert the path into mathematical formulae.

When I try, I notice that the blue line (using the SVG path string) doesn't quite match the red line (which is drawn using the mathematical formulae).

Am I doing something wrong, such as not properly understanding how to extract control points from the SVG path?

```js
let c = document.getElementById('c')
let ctx = c.getContext('2d')

ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue'
ctx.stroke(new Path2D(`M 0, 100  S 27, 2, 200 0`))

// bezier control points, derived from SVG path
let x1 = 0,    y1 = 100,
    x2 = 27,   y2 = 2,
    x3 = 200,  y3 = 0

ctx.strokeStyle = 'red'
ctx.beginPath()
ctx.moveTo(x1, y1)

for(let t=0; t<=1; t+=0.0001) {
  ctx.lineTo(
    (1-t)**2 * x1 + 2*(1-t) * t * x2 + t**2 * x3,
    (1-t)**2 * y1 + 2*(1-t) * t * y2 + t**2 * y3
  )
}
ctx.stroke()
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width="200" height="100"></canvas>
```

Comment: Do not edit your question to "add in the solution". IF the anwer(s) you get are enough to solve the problem, either accept the answer that solved it, or if the solution is more involved than using the information that an answer provides, you can write your own answer post and then accept that (after a cooldown period so folks don't use SO as a dumping ground for problems they already know the solution to =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'S' path command will draw a cubic Bézier curve, but your code seems to be drawing a quadratic curve. If I read the [SVG specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/paths.html#PathDataCubicBezierCommands) right (that’s a big "if", it’s not yet 7 in the morning here...), I think you need to repeat the (0, 100) point to get four points, and then generate a cubic curve from those.

Working code:

```js
let c = document.getElementById('c')
let ctx = c.getContext('2d')

ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue'
ctx.stroke(new Path2D(`M 0, 100  S 27, 2, 200 0`))

// bezier control points, derived from SVG path
let x1 = 0,    y1 = 100,
    x2 = 0,    y2 = 100,
    x3 = 27,   y3 = 2,
    x4 = 200,  y4 = 0

ctx.strokeStyle = 'red'
ctx.beginPath()
ctx.moveTo(x1, y1)

for(let t=0; t<=1; t+=0.0001) {
  ctx.lineTo(
    (1-t)**3 * x1 + 3*(1-t)**2 * t * x2 + 3*(1-t) * t**2 * x3 + t**3 * x4,
    (1-t)**3 * y1 + 3*(1-t)**2 * t * y2 + 3*(1-t) * t**2 * y3 + t**3 * y4,
  )
}
ctx.stroke()
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width="200" height="100"></canvas>
```

Comment: Quote from the spec: "The first control point is assumed to be the reflection of the second control point on the previous command relative to the current point. **If there is no previous command**..., assume the first control point is coincident with the current point."   – Yes, you read that right.

Comment: Thanks! I switched to the cubic formulae and it worked! (question edited to contain  working version)